# Absolute positioning in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, css-position

It works in IE/FF but not Chrome.

```
    html += '<div id = "note" style = "position: absolute; background-color:'
           + newcss[0] + '; margin-left:'
           + newcss[1] + '; margin-top:'
           + newcss[2] +  '; width = 100px; height = 100px;">'
           + newnote + '</div>';
```

Basically I am adding a new note into the page, with random colors, and position from left and top (stores in newcss).

Pic of IE vs Chrome (IE on left):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFZhD.png

EDIT: Yah that was a mistake; width: and height: fixes it to actually be the right size, but they still are all just pasted on the same spot right under the bar, rather than random spaces

EDIT2: I originally had them as separate ids (I was just messing around with jquery to see something haha)

Comment: `width = 100px; height = 100px;` isn't valid CSS. You probably meant `width: 100px; height: 100px;`.

Comment: why are you using `margin-top` and `margin-left` instead of `top` and `left`?

Comment: Additionally, it is invalid to have multiple elements with the same `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give it css of

```
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
margin-top: newcss[2];
margin-left: newcss[1];
display: block;
```

or just

```
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
```

Comment: Yes thank you this is what I was missing -- I thought it assumed >.<

Answer (score 1):

The css is incorrect. Css Style rules are in the form `key:val;` rather than `key=vale`. Absolute positioning allows you to define `top` `left` `bottom` and `right` values and places the object at that position ( either relative to the page or to the containing element ( if that element has `position:relative` set )). Use those for the placement of absolute elements.

Also you should probably be using the DOM objects rather than innerHTML.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');

div.setAttribute('class', 'note');

div.style.width = '100px';
div.style.height = '100px';
div.style.position = 'absolute';
div.style.backgroundColor = newcss[0];
div.style.top = newcss[1] + 'px';
div.style.left = newcss[2] + 'px';
container.appendChild(div);
```

Better even yet, defined the stuff that never changes as a style rule and then use the Javascript to only set the dynamic content.

```
.note {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Then all you have to do is set `top` `left` and `background-color`

```
div.setAttribute('class', 'note');
div.style.backgroundColor = newcss[0];
div.style.top = newcss[1] + 'px';
div.style.left = newcss[2] + 'px';
container.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
html += '<div class = "note" '
     + 'style="position: absolute; '
     + 'background-color:' + newcss[0] + '; '
     + 'left:' + newcss[1] + '; '
     + 'top:' + newcss[2] + '; '
     + 'width: 100px; height: 100px;">' + newnote + '</div>';
```

Changes:

- Changed `id` to `class`; it is invalid for two elements to have the same `id` in one document.
- Changed `margin-left` and `margin-top` to `left` and `top`.